# Winforms application shakes when loading if a background image is set

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

I set a background image for my forms, but when I run the application, the form shakes. If I remove the background image, the form doesn't shake. How can I set the background image without my form shaking?

Comment: so create a winform app, put a image background, run the project the form doesn't "shake". Can you put a link to the image?

Comment: yes i kept image background only but the form is getting shake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting the "DoubleBuffer" property on the form to true?
I had the same problem with a background flashing when the mouse was passing over a trasparent button.